Python subprocess passing args wrong
it seems some change in recent python versions introduced a different behavior of how subprocess.run parses arguments. A line that worked for years stopped working now.
Now, my python script wraps LaTex Songs and lilypond to generate chordsheets. After running into problems with python versions and lilypond's bundled python, I set up everything for a clean start. Maybe the fault isn't with python at all but with lilypond, however, I asked at the usually very responsive lilypond support and got no help.
So, here is the problem:
command = "lilypond-book.py --output="+args.output+" --pdf -lERROR --lily-loglevel=ERROR "+f
print(command)

prints:
lilypond-book.py --output=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\pyOut --pdf -lERROR --lily-loglevel=ERROR book_general.lytex
Pasting that output back to the shell works fine.
However, doing subprocess.run(command,shell=True) results in an error:
lilypond-book.py: error: file not found:  --output=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\pyOut --pdf -lERROR --lily-loglevel=ERROR book_general.lytex

It seems that using subprocess messes up the argument parsing for lilypond-book.py, it ignores the arguments and treats the whole command as "file". I also tried the prefered subprocess.run method using comma-separated arguments but got the same error.
Now, I'm pretty clueless.
I'm on Python 3.12.2, previous installed version was 3.7, IIRC. Lilypond is 2.24.4. OS is Windows 10.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Make your life easier by passing the arguments as a list to subprocess.run and don't use shell=True.

As suggested in comments, use a list of arguments directly if you already know how they should be separated and drop shell=True, the shell feature is generally much worse, never needed, and far more brittle (as you're finding out!) than an explicit list
Check out Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess !
p = subprocess.run(
    [
        "python",  # name in PATH
        "./lilypond-book.py",
        "--output=" + args.output,
        "--pdf",
        "-lERROR",
        "--lily-loglevel=ERROR",
        f,
    ],
)
p.check_returncode()  # check for success

You can use shlex.split() to get a shell-like splitting if you have a complete or a partial string which you for some reason don't want to parse yourself
And if you want to collect the output for other use, pass stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, which will fill the resulting CompletedProcess's .stderr and .stdout properties respectively
More from the official docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

The OP seems to be on Windows, where this works quite differently (to the extent that the verb "works" can be used at all when talking about this platform).

@tripleee yuck ): could you be more specific with different how and with .run() or output streams? (not that it surprises me to find incompatibility with even the most flexible and available APIs when Microsoft's love of mistreating their users is involved)

I avoid Windows like my life depended on it so I'm   not an expert; but Windows ends up assembling everything back into a string anyway, and the meaning of shell=True is somewhat more murky. It is obviously required for cmd built-ins like start and dir, but beyond that, IIRC, it doesn't do much on Windows. (I guess it could still matter for quoting but fortunately, I have no way to experiment.)

Just using subprocess.run(["lilypond-book.py", "--output="+args.output,"--pdf","-lERROR","--lily-loglevel=ERROR", f],shell=False) I get "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung" (sorry for the German text, however, that is what is shown to me).

ah, sorry, you'll probably need to prefix it with python (or python3) for it to know which executable to run (or perhaps provide the full path c:/wherever/python.exe) ["python", "lilypond-book.py", ...]

@☻ti7 it's strange that this is necessary even if I can run lilypond-book.py directly from cmd. But after providing python as first argument AND manually escaping the full path to lilypond-book.py, it works. Now I just need to make sure that this full path doesn't break the script on other machines sigh. Probably going to add the location of lilypobd-book to my config. Thank you!

excellent! plausibly a ./ prefix ("from here") is sufficient for Python to find the script rather than the full path too, or passing cwd to subprocess.run() "current working directory" if it's not the same as where you're running the script from (though I'm not sure how it would have worked before in such a case)
